# Error while trying to run Edge WebDriver through an service unknown error: Microsoft Edge failed to start: crashed

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-edgedriver

I have problem when using Selenium Edge driver running through a service . The error message i am getting is " unknown error: Microsoft Edge failed to start: crashed. (chrome not reachable) (The process started from msedge location...".The fun fact is that the same code is running with a WinForms test project . I checked driver versions installed/executing and all the possible problems could have caused this issue. Anyone can help me ?

I tried to get the source of an html file using Selenium Edge driver and webdriver waits

Comment: Have you tried to run your service using user account, not system?

Comment: I have tried to run it with admin permissions , i also changed the security options under the Program Files edge path so it will have full control of the edge.exe but still same error . Maybe the version i am currently running 113.0.1774.57 has some issues . I will try your suggestion to see the results

Answer (score 0):

The solution as it appears to be , is to run the service under local user account . Right click on the properties of the service , and hit Log on tab. Then you will set the user you would like the service to run and apply changes.